# Finding the minimum of an array from MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, arrays, minimum

Currently I am trying to find the minimum value within the array. The user types in the array they want to create and then the program is supposed to find the minimum. I have tried using the max_int value to find he minimum but I haven't had any success. How can I find the minimum within the array?

```java
public class Recursion {

    public static int findMin(int[] array, int index, int min) {
        int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < smallest) {
                smallest = array[i];
            }
            return findMin(array, index, min);
        }
        return smallest;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an extra `i++` inside the `array[i] < smallest` check

Comment: @user I had realized that right after I posted this but after removing it, it still doesn't return the smallest value.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. What are `index` and `min` for? Did you originally want to make a recursive solution?

Comment: Also, rather than posting that whole testing code, could you just give us a tiny test case that only calls `findMin` with some randomly generated values and nothing else, along with the output you got from findMin and the elements of the arrays you tried? See [mcve]

Comment: Could you show us what do you pass as arguments and what does it return? `findMin` looks to be OK.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. [It seems to work](https://ideone.com/DHjhQd).

Comment: You could do it without recursion, just loop through all elements in the array and cache the smallest. When the loop ends, return the smallest.

Comment: One more comment: Please make sure you post the code which, at least, compiles. You had a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description, you just need to find the min value in the array, so you don't need to use recursion for this problem. The following is an adaptation from your original code that does the job.

```
public static int findMin(int[] array) {
    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = array[i];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

If you can use the `Stream` interface, you can use a one liner for this problem.

```
 public static int findMin(int[] array) {
  return Arrays.stream(array).min().getAsInt();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do not just find min?

```
public static int findMin(int[] arr) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    
    for (int a : arr)
        min = Math.min(min, a);

    return min;
}
```

or even:

```
public static int findMin(int[] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).min().getAsInt();
}
```